# Data-Scraping Image URLs using excel?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, imageurl, vba

Is it possible to web-scrape image URLs using excel macros? To be clear, I want to scrape image-URLs and not the images.

If so, how?

I usually use the macros recorder to record functions that I don't remember, but the recorder doesn't pick up actions in my browser. So this suggests to me that it is not possible.

If not, what other tools have the function to data-scrape image urls?

Right now, to manually get image urls I have to go on the website, right-click on the image, and copy the image-url, and paste it into excel. There are over a 1000 images that I have to do this for. I have a long list of hyperlinks in excel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20623662/212869 my answer to this question could be adapted to scrape the url of your images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: Is it possible to data-scrape image URLs using excel macros?

A: Yes.

Q: If so, how?

A: You learn VBA syntax first. Then learn about SHDocVw.InternetExplorer or MSXML2.XMLHTTP, both can help you to determine the rul of the desired image. Finally [Download pictures from url and save in a folder named by a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742636/download-pictures-from-url-and-save-in-a-folder-named-by-a-cell) is an example to download image from url.

Comment: The pictures are not all on the same page. Here is the website: http://www.learnchineseez.com/read-write/traditional/view.php?code=7684&last=1. The pages are formatted the same way, but I'm not downloading all the images manually. I don't understand the latter part of your answer. I want to scrape image-urls, not the images.

Comment: If you just want the URL, not the actual image, then as suggested, use MSMXL to identify the URL and save it. You need to at least learn how to write some VBA without the macro recorder.